# Problem when booting Ubuntu - Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

Tags: boot, ntfs, fstab

When starting Ubuntu I get an error message that says:

```
An error occurred while mounting /windows.
Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery.
```

Searching the internet I saw that I should open the `/etc/fstab` file from the terminal, but when I open that file I do not know what to do. This is what appears in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=eff4b2da-0926-4c1e-aadc-cc1f02f13983 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=86d9aa0b-d72c-4050-8841-5cced37d5c45 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A809-EAE3  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=85f4c1f1-53a0-4c78-83e7-badaca16bf65 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /windows was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=EE28D21928D1E09F /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=02f941ad-edf0-4fe2-bf80-3536bbfd54af none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is what do you wish to do? You obviously have a windows partition on that machine that linux fails to mount.

Can you boot into that windows from GRUB?

Do you wish to keep that windows partition on the machine or not?

You can edit **/etc/fstab** in such a manner that linux will stop trying to mount that windows partition

From a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) run

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

and comment the line

```
UUID=EE28D21928D1E09F /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

by adding a **#** at the beginning of it like so:

```
# UUID=EE28D21928D1E09F /windows        ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46 0       0
```

This should stop linux from prompting that during boot, but you should address this issue  at its core and recover/remove that partition as you see fit.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Quisiera recuperar la partición. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? De nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: english please. Can you boot into that windows partition?

Comment: Truly I am new to ubuntu and only know I have that problem. thank you. I'm not sure I should do. I guess I should give m to recover manually, but I dont know there to do after

Comment: Your system probably doesn't need to have `/windows` mounted in order to boot, so you can just Skip mounting it, and analyse the problem once the system is booted.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error before I upgraded 12.04 to 14.04.  It occurs when I boot with my 1.5TB external USB HDD disconnected.

It is an EXT4 partition that is labeled "/Backup" and mounted under "/media/buck/Backup".  I had set up Deja Backup to automatically backup to that drive and I had a script that also backed up to the drive.

Since upgrading to 14.04 (yesterday) I have not had the problem.  But I also haven't re-established the automatic backup either.

At one time I had installed another version of Linux on the drive which included a swap partition. I since repartitioned the drive and strictly use it as a data drive and a place to do my backups.  I was guessing that the persistent connection was related to the missing swap partition.

Did you use an external drive with it that may have had a backup or swap partition? If so, you may check to see if plugging it in before you boot fixes it.

Answer (score -2):

You could try this:

```
 sudo umount
 sudo nano /etc/fstab
 sudo mount
```

and add this in to the line 14

```
 uuid=86d9aa0b-d72c-4050-8841-5cced37d5c45 /boot/efi   defaults boot errors=noremount     1
```

and add this in to the line 17

```
 uuid=EE28D21928D1E09F      /windows ntfs     defaults.umask=007,gid=46  errors=noremount    1
```

and then to line to line 19

```
 uuid=02f941ad-edf0-4fe2-bf80-3536bbfd54af /   swap  defaults   errors=noremount    1
```

and it might work fine this way.